# Which notation and why: $\text{P}()$, $\Pr()$, $\text{Prob}()$, or $\mathbb{P}()$

Tags: probability, notation

Are these merely stylistic conventions (whether italicized or non-italicized), or are there substantive differences in the meanings of these notations?

Are there other notations meaning "*the probability of*" that should be considered in this question?

Comment: I feel like I see $\mathbb{P}()$ more in the context of measure theoretic probability.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Stylistic conventions, mainly, but with some underlying rationale.

$\mathbb{P}()$ and $\Pr()$ can be seen as two ways to "free up" the letter $\text{P}$ for other use—it *is* used to denote other things than "probability", for example in research with complicated and extensive notation where one starts to exhaust available letters.

$\mathbb{P}()$ requires special fonts, which is a disadvantage. $\Pr()$ may be useful when the author would want the reader to think of probability in abstract and general terms, using the second lower-capital letter "$r$" to disassociate the symbol as a whole from the usual way we write up functions.

For example, some problems are solved when one remembers that the cumulative distribution function of a random variable can be written and treated as a probability of an "inequality-event", and apply the basic probability rules rather than functional analysis.

In some cases, one may also see $\text {Prob}()$, again, usually in the beginning of an argument that will end up in a specific formulation of how this probability is functionally determined.

The *italics* version $P()$ is also used, and also in lower-case form, $p()$—this last version is especially used when discussing discrete random variables (where the *probability mass function* *is* a probability).

$\pi(\;,\;)$ is used for conditional ("transition") probabilities in Markov Theory.

Comment: Thank you, I have included $\text{Prob}()$ in an edit to my question. Also: <GASP> "it *is* used to denote other things than 'probability'" say it ain't so! ;) I think also that $\pi$ is sometimes used to describe the parameter corresponding to $p$ in a PMF.

Comment: Well, Alexis, GASP indeed, but this is why when reading a paper, never skip its preparatory sections -it is where the author defines the symbolic language he will use -and if he doesn't, he is sloppy.

Comment: I disagree on one point: I have mostly seen $p()$ used for a _continuous_ random variable --- the thinking being that its probability density function evaluated at a point is similar to but distinct from the probability mass function of a discrete random variable evaluated at a point, which is a probability and can be denoted by $P()$. It is also my impression that $P()$ is more common than $\text{P}()$.

Comment: @Nagel That's interesting. In which field?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: I am sure I have seen it repeatedly in statistical machine learning; I thought I had seen it in pure statistics texts too, but I shan't say for certain.

Comment: @Nagel. I wouldn't know about machine learning, but in Information Theory, and Econometrics, lower case $p(x)$ denotes usually a probability mass function. $p$ alone denotes usually a specific probability. $P()$ is the general symbol for probability of any $()$. Probability density functions in mathematical statistics are predominantly denoted by $f(x)$ or better $f_{X}(x)$, and other function-related symbols like $g$ or $h$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I'm also used to seeing $p(x)$ used to denote a density function, and $P$ to denote a probability mass.  This seems a common convention in physics (in my experience, at least).

Comment: @WillVousden Yes, notational conventions are not consistent across discipline, in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen all three used in different undergrad classes and as far as I know, they're stylistic differences and all represent probability as you're thinking of it.

One other notation I've seen is in Sheldon Ross's "Introduction to Probability Theory", where $\mathbf{P}$ represents a probability matrix.  He also uses $\pi_i$ as a notation for limiting probability, which a sequence of probabilities $(p_i)$ converges to.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that $\pi$ and $p$ in the sense that you are referring to correspond to parameters and estimates of, say, a Bernouli or binomial distribution?

Comment: I pretty much always see $\theta$ used to represent a parameter in one of those distributions.  Occasionally I've seen $p$ used as the parameter, but never $\pi$.  I've never seen $\pi$ used outside the context of limiting probabilities.  I'm not sure but I think it fits into the whole "use English letters for statistics and Greek letters for parameters" paradigm.

Comment: And yet $p$ is a Latin (not English) letter (i.e. statistic), and $\pi$ is a Greek letter (i.e. parameter?).

Comment: Depends on the context.  I've only seen $\pi$ used in the context of limiting probabilities in stochastic processes.  In that specific situation, the $p$s converge to $\pi$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: You misunderstand my comment, the Latin-ness or Greek-ness of those letters does not in any way depend on context.

Comment: Oh my bad.  Yeah, obviously $p$ is Latin and $\pi$ is Greek.  But the analogy I was trying to make is that $\bar{x} \to \mu$ as $n \to \infty$, and $\bar{x}$ is Latin and $\mu$ is Greek.  Similarly, in stochastic processes, $p \to \pi$ as $n \to \infty$ and $p$ is Latin and $\pi$ is Greek.

Answer (score 2):

This makes me think of [Meyn and Tweedie's book](http://probability.ca/MT/BOOK.pdf). They use $P$ to denote the transition kernel for a Markov chain, and $\mathsf{P}$ for the law of the entire chain on $\mathsf{X}^{\infty}$. This answer is specific to Markov chains, but the distinction is obviously important.

The difference between $P$ and $\mathbb{P}$ (and $E$ and $\mathbb{E}$) from book to book, is just for aesthetic appeal, in my opinion. I can't generalize where I see $\Pr()$ or $\text{Prob}()$, really.

Comment: +1 And, as with @29740 's comments, the italic-serif/Roman sans-serif somewhat parallels the Latin/Greek convention for estimate/estimand.