# What does Pr() mean?

Tags: regression, probability, distributions, notation

What does the expression $Pr(x|y;\theta)$ mean?
As in:
$$
{\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}L(\theta |x)&=Pr(Y|X;\theta )\\&=\prod _{i}Pr(y_{i}|x_{i};\theta )\\&=\prod _{i}h_{\theta }(x_{i})^{y_{i}}(1-h_{\theta }(x_{i}))^{(1-y_{i})}\end{aligned}}}
$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Model_fitting

I've never been able to figure out what $Pr$ means. What's the difference versus $P$?

Comment: It's "Probability".

Comment: It is the probability that Y$_i$=$y_i$ for each i given that $x_i$ for each i and $\theta$ are known.

Comment: Why not $P(x|y;\theta)$ then?
And also, does that mean $Pr(a|b;c;d)$ means that it's the probability of $a$ given $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10234/35989

Answer (score 1):

$\Pr()$ is pretty standard notation used to denote probability. In case of $\Pr(Y|X;\theta)$ it's conditional probability of $Y$ given $X$ and $ \theta$.

See also similar thread [Difference between $p(x)$ vs. $\pi(x)$ in literature](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/296677/35989)

Comment: Why not just $P(Y|X;\theta)$?

Comment: @oink Why $P$ should be "better" then $p$ or $\Pr$? Simply several different notations exist.

Comment: +1 but I vote to close this whole thread as a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108441/

Comment: @amoeba good point, agree.